# Android string kernel version

Tags: android, kernel

I am trying to understand the kernel version available at the settings of the device.

My device, for example, have the following kernel version:

Kernel version:
3.4.0-1565445
se.infra@SWDB2914 #1
SMP PEEMPT Wed Aug 13 03:54:31 KST 2014

Could anyone explain me each element of this string? And how can I get this through the Android SDK.

Thanks and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

to get kernel version in your app use this string

```
 String kernel = System.getProperty("os.version");
```

Comment: I tested this function. It returns just the "3.4.0-1565445" of the example.

Comment: I would like to know what mean "se.infra@SWDB2914 #1 SMP PEEMPT Wed Aug 13 03:54:31 KST 2014" and how to get this in my app as well.